# why does return type of values in iterator not a set?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

In the Map Interface

```
  Collection<V> values();
```

Why does this function does not return Set similarly to `entrySet()` and `keySet()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Make it the other way round -  Why would it return a `Set`?

Comment: What if map has same values few times and you want to know about it?

Comment: @Pshemo Got your answer . Also ,why keyset() returns Set.

Comment: @Thinker because all keys in Map are unique so Set is most appropriate type to return them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In a map, keys are unique but can map to the same value.**

Put another way:

- The values are not necessarily unique and therefore cannot be stored in a set without losing duplicates.
- The keys and the entires, on the other hand, are unique.

Answer (score 1):

Becasue, `Set`s do not allow duplicates and your `Map` could have two keys mapping to the same value. `Map` only requires its keys to be unique not its values.

Answer (score 1):

The keyset of a Map is a Set, while values is a Collection:

```
public interface Map<K,V> {

    // Basic operations
    V put(K key, V value);
    V get(Object key);
    V remove(Object key);
    boolean containsKey(Object key);
    boolean containsValue(Object value);
    int size();
    boolean isEmpty();

    // Bulk operations
    void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m);
    void clear();

    // Collection Views
    public Set<K> keySet();
    public Collection<V> values();
```

And as to why is keyset a Set, and values a Collection, you have your answer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html):

> values — The Collection of values contained in the Map. This
>   Collection is not a Set, because multiple keys can map to the same
>   value.

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` has a unique set of keys and each key is mapped to a value.

A `Set` contains a unique set of values. By it's contract it cannot contain duplicates.

So, lets start with a `Map` that looks like this:

```
final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ONE", "TEST");
map.put("TWO", "TEST");
```

So the `keySet` returns a `Set` of `ONE, TWO`. But the values are `TEST, TEST`, these are not unique so they cannot be put into a `Set`.